# Data Not getting saved in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying this code but data is not getting saved and it is throwing an error

```
<?php 
include 'core/int.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';


if(!empty($_POST)){
$add_status = $insert->add_status($user_data['user_id']);
}
?>

  
  <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name = "question_time" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo time()?>" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Post your Question <?php echo $user_data['username'];?></h2>
                <textarea name = "question"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </form>
```

and the function is defined like this :

```
function add_status($user_id){

mysql_query("INSERT into `post` (user_id, status_time, status_content) VALUES($user_id, '$_POST[question_time]', '$_POST[question]')");
}
```

It is throwing and error that

> Undefined variable: insert in C:\wamp\www\zr\sheet.php on line 7
>
> Call to a member function add_status() on a non-object in   C:\wamp\www\zr\sheet.php on line 7
>
> Line 7 is "$add_status = $insert->add_status($user_data['user_id']);"

I am a new learner in PHP and MYSQL

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The notice speaks for itself, doesn't it? Plus, you wouldn't be mixing MySQL APIs by any chance?

Comment: `mysql_` functions do not work on the current Wamp version. There isn't enough code/information for a concrete answer, including which API you are using to connect with.

Comment: What class is $insert instantiating? Where does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
function add_status($id, $status_time, $status_content)
{
    $db = //your db connection
    $query = $mysqli_query('INSERT into table WHERE user_id, status_time, status_content VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $db->bind_param('i,i,s' $id, $status_time, $status_content);
    $db->execute();
}
```

and then call it as

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $questionTime = $_POST['question_time'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $allFields = $questionTime . $question;

    if (!empty($allFields)) {
        $insert->add_status($user_data['user_id'], $questionTime, $question);
    }
}
```

Remember, always use prepared statements and NEVER use `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use This Code]

first of all, you should extract using POST. This is the ideal way..